# How can I implement RestAPI who supports Saml protocol in Android/Java?

Tags: android, oauth, single-sign-on, server, saml

I am a beginner in android development. I want to create a SAML sample in Android. I went to read the basic specification of saml v2.0 and some concepts on single sign on.

I could not find any site how to implement saml and sso for android or any other domain.

I really need big help on knowing the Saml, Single sign on, Service Provider, Indentity Provider(Idp) and OAuth.

Comment: Anybody has an answer for this?